# what is the simplest way to express this expected value of a product of two variables?

Tags: probability

I need the expected value of the product of two variables for an application I am considering, e.g. $E(xy)$.

As a secondary problem I will also need $E(xyH(x>k))$  where $H(x>k)$ is a Heaviside/indicator variable that is one for $x>k$ and zero otherwise.

The marginal distributions of both $x$ and $y$ are known precisely but the nature of the correlation between the two needs to be fitted, or at least different models of it need to be considered.

For an initial assessment, I simply wrote the expectation in terms of covariance between the two, exploiting $cov(x,y)=E(xy)-E(x)E(y)$, however, I need to examine different values under different types of correlation.

This sounds like a good candidate for using copulas (a subject I have only scant knowledge of).

Assume the variables are as continuous as required.

The first question would be:
can the expectation be written in a form that involves the moments or cumulants of the two marginal distributions and  the copula representing this joint distribution?
and
can the simplicity of the required expectation be exploited to write it in as simple a form as possible?
I have a nagging suspicion that at least the first expected value can be written simply in terms of an underlying copula and then a comparisons between different copulas can be made directly.

Thanks for any pointers!

Comment: There's no general way to compute $\int xy dF(x,\,y)$. Do you know any more about the distribution? In some cases, you know the correlation coefficient, say $\rho$; then $E(xy)=\mu_x\mu_y+\rho\sigma_x\sigma_y$.

Comment: Sorry..a malfunction replying. The problem is one of financial derivative valution, so the task is to fit a function that can value These instruments. What I was hoping for was to get a form for the valuation that was (a) "as simple as possible but no simpler" and (b) splits the fitting into into two,tasks one to fit the marginal distributions and two to fit the correlation behaviour. Simple linear correlation may be enough but I suspect not. 
What I was wondering about is, is there a way to write this expectation in Terms of the moments of the two marginals and a 
function of a copula.

Comment: To be more explicit, in the Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)
under the heading "Expectation for copula models and Monte Carlo Integration" if you take the arbitrary function g to be simple the product of two variables, then I believe there is a Cornish Fisher style formula for the inverse for a Distribution function. If you plug that in you get the expectation is a series with coefficients related to the cumulants and also integrals over a copula.